# Using Moq with HttpPostedFileBase and one other parameter

Tags: c#, moq, httppostedfilebase

I have a method that takes 2 parameters like:

```
assetService(assetDto dto, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
```

and i can't use moq with this. How can i do that? (using 'moq')

---

```
public ResultObjectDto CreateAsset(AssetDto model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

and i want to moq this

```
Assert.IsTrue(_assetService.CreateAsset(new AssetDto(), postedFileBase).ResultType == ResultType.Error);
```

this moq is wrong, how can i do that

Comment: _and i can't use moq with this_ What do you mean? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i try to writing unit tests with moq. i have a file upload method that takes httppostedfileparameter but i can't fix it. there are many example with httppostedfile base but my method takes two parameter and i couldn't fix it.

Comment: Post an example of one of the unit tests. I still don't know what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I'm sorry, i was late.

i update my question above

Comment: I'm also a little confused at what you are trying to do. Are you trying to mock the `HttpPostedFileBase`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is "HttpPostedFileBase"

Comment: man literally the first result from google for "moq HttpPostedFileBase" is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622153/mocking-httppostedfilebase-and-inputstream-for-unit-test Just Mock the HttpPostedFileBase and call the test exactly as you have in the Assert where the postedFileBase is the mock object.

Answer (score 1):

First you have a class you want to mock with a method with several parameters

```
public class foo
{
    public virtual int bar(int num, string str, bool b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

than to make a test you mock it

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    //Mock of the foo class
    var t = new Mock<foo>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    //Setup to return what we want 0 instead of 1
    t.Setup(e => e.bar(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
                  .Returns((int i, string s, bool b) => { return 0; });

    //the actual object
    var f = t.Object;
    //the actual test
    Assert.AreEqual(0, f.bar(1, "s", false));
}
```

Comment: How about HttpPostedFile ?

Comment: basically you setup all methods and properties to return what you expect from the HttpPostedFile object for the test.